# Displaying json in a ListView

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display a json (array of movies objects) insight ListView component but receive the error: **cannot read property cloneWithRows of undefined**. What exactly I am doing wrong? I found a lot of tutorials and they all use hard coded data and can't see how it is used when the data is from request. Here is my code:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = { dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([]) };
}


componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2')
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(this.onAfterLoad)
        .catch(this.manageError);
}

// We will update the state of the application so that images can render
onAfterLoad = (data) => {
    this.setState({ dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(data.Search) });
};

// If there is an error show error    
manageError = (error) => {
    Alert.alert('Failure fetching data');
    console.error(error);
};

// Description: Render all the titles
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

renderRow(rowData) {
    console.log(rowData);
    return <Movie key={rowData.imdbID} data={rowData} />;
}

// Description: Render everything to the screen
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

render() {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(data.Search)
```

should be

```
dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tutorials)
```

inside onAfterLoad() method.